Logarithm expansion around singularity
I'm having trouble verifying the following expansion for $|z\lambda| < 1$ given by WolframAlpha. Is there a general strategy given the singularity at $z=0$?
\begin{align*}
        \mathrm{Taylor}_{z=0}
        \frac{z\lambda - z\lambda\log(1 - z\lambda)+\log(1-z\lambda)}{z\lambda^2(z\lambda - 1)}
        &=
        \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{-(k+1)}{k+2}z^{k+1}
        \lambda^{k}
    \end{align*}

Is there more to it than just multiplying by $z\lambda^2(z\lambda - 1)$ and checking that what you get is the Maclaurin series of $z\lambda - z\lambda(1 - z\lambda) + \log(1 - z\lambda)$?

$\newcommand\la\lambda$Note that
$$A_z(\la):=\frac{z\lambda - z\lambda\ln(1 - z\lambda)+\ln(1-z\lambda)}{z\lambda^2(z\lambda - 1)}
=\frac1\la\,\frac{h(\la z)}{\la z}, \tag{1}\label{1}$$
where
$$h(u):=1-\frac1{1-u}-\ln(1-u).$$
It is easy to get the Maclaurin series for $h(u)$.  Now the desired result follows from \eqref{1}.
